# Eclipse - Comp Issues

Tags: java, string, eclipse, int, this

So I am trying to build a Email Admini App on Eclipse but there is a issue that I am
having. The console says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
email cannot be resolved to a type

at emailapp.EmailApp.main(EmailApp.java:6)
```

Here is my code that I have written already in my 2 classes:

package emailapp;

public class EmailApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Email em1 = new email("Goanar","Rambang");
}
```

}

```
public class Email {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String department; 
    private int mailboxCapacity;
    private String alternateEmail; 
    
    //The Blueprint - Template
    // Add constructor for first and last name
    // Ask for department]
    // Generate random password
    // Set mailbox capacity
    // Set the alternate email
    // Change the password 

    //Constructor*/
    public Email(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        System.out.println("EMAIL CREATED " + this.firstName + "" + this.lastName);
    }
}
```

Any reasons why I may be screwing up my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `main` method, `Email em1 = new email("Goanar","Rambang");` where `new email("Goanar","Rambang");` should be `new Email("Goanar","Rambang");`

Comment: Thank you so much! Im a beginner at coding so knowing that your code could be screwed by just a capitalized letter is crazy to me! Thanks again! :)

Comment: Yes, pretty much everything is case sensitive.